# Implement user login/out without database using Play framework

Tags: authentication, web, playframework

I am using play framework to develop a web app. Now I need to implement authentication/authorisation **without database** (really strange requirement). There will only be log in and log out function, no registration. The username/password pair will be authenticated using external service.

Due to limited experience, my current idea is to use token to authenticate and a local file to store username/password.

Is my idea feasible? Is there any recommended libs? If I use token, do I need to pass that token in Http request/response every time and authenticate the token in every controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why store user name and passwords in a local file? I don't see the point and this constitutes a database, which you want to avoid it seems... Deciding to work with local files will be an important limitation if you ever want to deploy more than one server and have some load-balancing done.

Playframework is stateless, meaning that the server doesn't keep session state. To work around that play uses signed session cookies (the browser is storing the session data, and cannot modify it as the session data is signed).

Here's what you can do:

- on login: set some data in the session
- on each subsequent request, determine the state (logged-in or not) based on the session cookie, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Authentication
- on logout: reset the session cookie

Now this approach has a serious downside, it allows people to replay (reuse) old session cookies to pretend being logged. Another (could be less serious depending on your requirements) is that it is not straightforward to implement session expiration after a certain inactivity.

This is probably enough to answer your question and give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenments. I wanted to store credentials in local file because I need  username/password in many other services and helpers, but after reading your answer, I can see it lacks consideration. I will read the link, thanks again.

Comment: On top of the above storing credentials this way requires very careful design, otherwise it could quickly become a security nightmare.